# Adding text to swatch area on product pages?

Tags: magento2, swatches

I'd like to add text below each attribute on the product options form section of the product page.

So, for example, something like:

```
Size
[s][m]
Appended text here
```

I can tell this is directly related to /module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml, but the stuff I'd like to edit is generated by this js:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=swatch-options]": {
            "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer": {
                "jsonConfig": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                "jsonSwatchConfig": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
                "mediaCallback": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMediaCallback() ?>",
                "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar('gallery_switch_strategy',
                    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct') ?: 'replace'; ?>"
            },
            "Magento_Swatches/js/configurable-customer-data": {
                    "swatchOptions": <?php /* @noEscape */ echo $swatchOptions ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you wanting static text, or do you want the text to change based on the attribute value? Does the text need to change when an attribute value is selected?

Comment: I actually want to add, for each attribute, the value of that attribute's "description" -- a field I've added using this module: https://github.com/dmatthew/magento2-attribute-description

Comment: Do you think I'd need to override/alter some of the methods in \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable to pass some additional JSON data, and then somehow grab that data in swatch-renderer.js? I barely know what I'm talking about here, but it smells like the right direction.

Comment: Kind of sounded like it should be there from the description of the product - https://packagist.org/packages/dmatthew/magento2-attribute-description

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I'm still unsure how to actually render it.

Comment: Try on a default theme if you can. But I'm sure it has something to do with

 /** @var $attribute Dmatthew\AttributeDescription\Model\Entity\Attribute **/
$description = $attribute->getStoreDescription($storeId);

Just not familiar with it

Comment: Yeah, I figured, but I can't figure out -where- to put this, since those swatches are being rendered from that js file.

Comment: Hey @dawhoo, I got it! Just had to throw item.description in the containter.append() in swatch-renderer.js

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by editing `swatch-renderer.js`, in the `container.append()` function in the `_RenderControls` block:

```
  container.append(
                    '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code + '" ' +
                         'attribute-code="' + item.code + '" ' +
                         'attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
                        label +
                        '<div aria-activedescendant="" ' +
                             'tabindex="0" ' +
                             'aria-invalid="false" ' +
                             'aria-required="true" ' +
                             'role="listbox" ' + listLabel +
                             'class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
                            options + select +
                        '</div>' + input +
                    '</div>' + '<div class="my-extra-stuff">' + item.description + '</div>'
                );
```

(In my case, I grabbed the newly-created item.description from the JSON object)

Comment: I would suguest you to add your custom text using your custom js without changing in `swatch-renderer.js`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can add a `phtml`file on that page with custom `js` script. In this script you can write code to append text below your swatches.